# Are both source code changes and environment setting changes of vcproject reflected in git when commit (push)?

Tags: xcode, git, visual-studio-2017

In the process of building the team library, I changed the environment settings of some vcprojects and wondered if they are reflected in git when I commit (push) them.

Only changes to the source code are reflected ??

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git` versions files.

If it is not in a file, it is not versioned ; if it is in one of the vcproject's files, it will be versioned.

Comment: You're welcome. I wrote that response a bit quickly. If it answers your question : please mark it as accepted. If you have further interrogations : please edit your question to precise your needs.

Comment: Glad to know it was enough ! :)